# ASP Global.Application_BeginRequest() not being called when using FileUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am trying to use a **FileUpload** control to upload files in my asp website, however, if the file size exceeds the **maxRequestLength** as indicated in the **Web.config** of my website, the page times out. In order to prevent this, I am trying to insert the following code into Global:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (Request.ContentLength > MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/ErrorMaxFileSizeExceeded.aspx");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above code is never reached when the maxRequestLength is exceeded, but why? The browser indicates that it starts to upload the file, with the progress visible to the user, however the progress is stuck at **0%**.

There are many suggestions of increasing the **maxRequestLength** to accommodate user uploads, however, this is not a good fix. It is possible that some of my user would attempt (locally) to upload massive files possibly reaching 1GB. I need to provide an appropriate error message without the page timing out.

Additional: Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-KnoLex-20140916165248;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-KnoLex-20140916165248.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!-- change here for max file upload size-->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480000" enable ="true"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you show the code of web.config please?

Comment: Sure. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Better you use Validation function on client end (i.e. using javascript)

- Javascript

`<script type="text/javascript" >
        function Validate() {
            var msg = "";
            var bIsValid = true;
            var uploadedFile = document.getElementById("<%=fileUpload.ClientID %>"); 
            if (uploadedFile.files[0].size > 20480000) // greater than size
            {
                msg += "File Size is limited to 20480000 !";
                alert(msg);
                bIsValid = false;
                return false;
            }
            //On Success
            return true;
        }
</script>`

**call this function `Validate()`** on button `OnClientClick` event to prevent user upload file more than your defined size.